# socket.on does not work in Node.JS (clientside)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My socket.on code does not work on the clientside, but on the serverside.
I have 2 pages, one to socket.emit(so I can call it whenever I want to) and one (the main/index page) to listen for the emit `socket.on`.

Servercode:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(8080));

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('playerData', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Clientcode:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script> 
<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
socket.on('playerData', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

I am using Node.JS - Jade, Express, Socket.io (and AngularJS, but not in this part of the code)

As already mentioned, the Serverside console.log is being called when I call my emit function, but on the Clientside nothing happens.
Currently using Chrome as my browser.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does it connect to the server?

Comment: It does connect and I don't get any errors. If it wouldn't connect the emit won't work, but I forgot to mention this.

Comment: Are you sure you are emitting the `playerData` event to the client?

Comment: I don't know. How can I emit to every client?

Comment: You can emit on connection to this socket only to test. Otherwise you can use `io.sockets.emit('playerData', 'some data');`